# Html - Table's Td element is not getting fixed

Tags: html, css, angular

I created a normal table that contains Start date and End Date as two table data element. There are some validations written that appear once the expectations are not met. However, when the validations get fired, it is changing the layout of other td and moving the element a little bit lower than first td. Below is the screenshot for more reference
[image]

However, when the validations are not fired, it is working as expected:

[image]

Below is the code that I have used:

```html
<table *ngIf="isRecurrenceSelected">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px">
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="minStartDate && isStartDateTimeVisible">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <date-time-selection ref-start="ngModel" name="startDateTime" 
          [minDate]="minStartDate" 
          [(ngModel)]="startDateTime" 
          (ngModelChange)="startTimeChanged($event)"
          [isRecurrenceSelectedFromEquipmentSchedule]="isRecurrenceSelected">
            {{ (isRecurrenceSelected ? "RUNTIME.SHARED.BASE_SCHEDULE_CHANGE_DIALOGS.RECURRENCE_START_DATE" : "RUNTIME.SHARED.BASE_SCHEDULE_CHANGE_DIALOGS.START_DATE_TIME") | translate:lang }}
          </date-time-selection>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="start.errors && start.dirty" class="help-block">
          <div *ngIf="start.errors.dateTimeSelectionValid" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_REQUIRED</div>
          <div *ngIf="start.errors.dateComesAfter" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_NOT_CURRENT_FOR_ALL_DAY</div>
          <div *ngIf="start.errors.dateInRange?.minError" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>
            RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_IN_PAST
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px; padding-left:5px">
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="minEndDate && isEndDateTimeVisible && !endTimeOptional">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <date-time-selection ref-end="ngModel" name="endDateTime" 
          [minDate]="minEndDate" 
          [(ngModel)]="endDateTime" 
          (ngModelChange)="endTimeChanged($event)" 
          [disabled]="!isEndDateTimeEditable" 
          [jciDateComesAfter]="!isAllDay && startDateTime" 
          [isDateOnly]="isAllDay"
          jciDateTimeSelectionValid 
          [jciDateInRange]="{compareDatesOnly: isAllDay, includeHourBoundary: isAllDay}" [isRecurrenceSelectedFromEquipmentSchedule]="isRecurrenceSelected">
            {{ (isRecurrenceSelected ? "RUNTIME.SHARED.BASE_SCHEDULE_CHANGE_DIALOGS.RECURRENCE_END_DATE" : "RUNTIME.SHARED.BASE_SCHEDULE_CHANGE_DIALOGS.END_DATE_TIME") | translate:lang }}
          </date-time-selection>
          <div *ngIf="!isRecurrenceSelected && options.scheduleCategory!=='equipment'" class="allDayContainer">
            <div *ngIf="isAllDayAllowed" class="allDayContainer">
              <input id="allDay" name="allDay" type="checkbox" 
              [(ngModel)]="isAllDay" 
              (ngModelChange)="onAllDayChanged($event)" />
              <label for="allDay">All day schedule</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="end.errors && end.dirty" class="help-block">
          <div *ngIf="end.errors.jciDateTimeSelectionValid" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_END_REQUIRED</div>
          <div *ngIf="end.errors.jciDateComesAfter" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_END_FLIPPED</div>
          <div *ngIf="end.errors.jciDateInRange?.minError" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>
            RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_END_IN_PAST
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am not able to figure out when css change I need to make so that the other TD element get in line with the first one.

Comment: It is supposed to behave like this. Because the warning text doesn't appear below the second date input. Try showing the alert text outside the table row

Comment: First question that pops up: why do you need a `table` to display this information?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the following code. I just used two divs and then incorporated those into a table. This helped me adjusting the warning text.

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>

                            <div style="float: left; width:200px">
                                <div class="form-group" *ngIf="minStartDate && isStartDateTimeVisible">
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <date-time-selection ref-start="ngModel"
                                                                 name="startDateTime"
                                                                 [minDate]="minStartDate"
                                                                 [(ngModel)]="startDateTime"
                                                                 (ngModelChange)="startTimeChanged($event)"
                                                                 [disabled]="!isStartDateTimeEditable"
                                                                 [dateComesAfter]="isAllDay && minStartDate"
                                                                 [isDateOnly]="isAllDay">
                                            {{ (isRecurrenceSelected ? "RUNTIME.SHARED.BASE_SCHEDULE_CHANGE_DIALOGS.RECURRENCE_START_DATE" : "RUNTIME.SHARED.BASE_SCHEDULE_CHANGE_DIALOGS.START_DATE_TIME") | translate:lang }}
                                        </date-time-selection>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="start.errors && start.dirty" class="help-block">
                                        <div *ngIf="start.errors.dateTimeSelectionValid" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_REQUIRED</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="start.errors.dateComesAfter" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_NOT_CURRENT_FOR_ALL_DAY</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="start.errors.dateInRange?.minError" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>
                                            RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_IN_PAST
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div style="float: left; width:200px">
                                <div class="form-group" *ngIf="minEndDate && isEndDateTimeVisible && !endTimeOptional">
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <date-time-selection ref-end="ngModel"
                                                                 name="endDateTime"
                                                                 [minDate]="minEndDate"
                                                                 [(ngModel)]="endDateTime"
                                                                 (ngModelChange)="endTimeChanged($event)"
                                                                 [disabled]="!isEndDateTimeEditable">{{ (isRecurrenceSelected }}
                                        </date-time-selection>
                                        <div *ngIf="!isRecurrenceSelected && options.scheduleCategory!=='equipment'" class="allDayContainer">
                                            <div *ngIf="isAllDayAllowed" class="allDayContainer">
                                                <input id="allDay" name="allDay" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isAllDay" (ngModelChange)="onAllDayChanged($event)" />
                                                <label for="allDay">All day schedule</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="end.errors && end.dirty" class="help-block">
                                        <div *ngIf="end.errors.dateTimeSelectionValid" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_END_REQUIRED</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="end.errors.dateComesAfter" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_START_END_FLIPPED</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="end.errors.dateInRange?.minError" class="text-danger" l10nTranslate>
                                            RUNTIME.INPUT_DATA.COMMON_ERRORS.E_END_IN_PAST
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```